# Como importar un procedimiento almacenado de local a remoto?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Verán, tengo una bd en mi local la cual tiene procedimientos almacenados,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
```

Yo quiero expórtalos a mi bd en remoto, pero me da un error, que es que tengo que ser usuario SUPER, no se como hacer eso, alguien que me pueda ayudar
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si uno mira la [documentación oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) de MySQL (que siempre será una opción recomendada), ve que esta opción DEFINER no es requerida. Sólo necesitas que el usuario con el que estás conectado tenga permisos para crear lo que sea que vayas a crear.

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])
[characteristic ...] routine_body
```

Así pues, con tu usuario `pepito` puedes ir y simplemente hacer `CREATE PROCEDURE xyz...`, quitando esos fragmentos `definer=root@localhost` de tus export o de los scripts generados automágicamente (que es donde suele venir ese tipo de instrucciones.